# Why do string printed using 'print' in clojure only appear in my console after I use println?

Tags: printing, clojure

I have the following code in clojure:

```
(do
    (println "starting....")
    (sig! a 0)
    (sig! b 0)
    (future
      (Thread/sleep 4000)
      (println "switch 1")
      (sig! a 1)
      (sig! b 0)
      (Thread/sleep 4000)
      (println "switch 2")
      (sig! a 0)
      (sig! b 1)
      (Thread/sleep 4000)
      (println "switch 3")
      (sig! a 1)
      (sig! b 1)) nil))
```

I have some watchers that listen to the atoms a, b, s, and c1 and print out some strings when they change. Using `(print (str uid ":" @o "\n")` or the println version. The clojure docs say `print` and `println` should behave exactly the same way, with the exception of the newline in `println`, however I'm not seeing this.
When the watcher uses `println` I see the strings right away. When the watcher uses `print`. I only see the output when the next `println` is called.  Below I have the output with `println` vs with `print`. 
With `print` I only see the values up to the last `println`.

```
starting....
switch 1
a:1
s:1
switch 2
a:0
b:1
s:0
s:1
switch 3
```

Now with println

```
starting....
switch 1
a:1

s:1

switch 2
a:0
b:1


s:0

s:1

switch 3
a:1

s:0

c1:1
```

As you can see the changes picked up by the watchers are printed in this case.  I'm using clojure 1.5.  It almost seems like a `print` requires a `println` to flush its contents to console.

Answer (score 6):

After looking more closely at the Clojure source [code](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/println) for `println` and `print`.  The difference is that `println` calls `prn` and print calls `pr`.  In the `prn` the **[function](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/newline)** `newline` is called.  It then checks for *flush-on-new-line* and if it is true it explicitly calls `flush`. Therefore calling `print` with any number of newlines ("\n") in the string will not flush to the output stream, you must either call `newline`, or call `flush` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Output doesn't actually go to console until it is flushed. Generally, printing a newline character is the default signal for the console to flush the output. You can generally force this in most languages with a call to a flush function, in most IO libraries.

Comment: I was actually printing using `(print (str uid ":" @o "\n")` so there was a new line but I didn't work.

Comment: @rileyfreeman You should have mentioned that in the first place. Please update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Clojure documentation](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.core/%2aflush-on-newline%2a), output is flushed by default on every newline. So you'll probably have to explicitly flush the output to get what you want.